# VS 2010, TFS 2008, build server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Can you combine TFS 2008 with a build server running Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about something like what is covered here?

http://richardsbraindump.blogspot.com/2009/11/how-to-build-vs2010-solutions-using.html